# Looping through Object for Select Option fails with bootstrap-select

Tags: reactjs, redux, bootstrap-select

I am using [bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/), ReactJS and Rudux. When I manually create the select as follows, it works:

```html
<select className="selectpicker">
  <option>Select a sport</option>
  <option>Baseball</option>
  <option>Football</option>
</select>
```

When I create a select field, using an object to populate the options, it works:

```html
<select>
  <option>Select a Sport</option>
  {Object.keys(this.props.sports).map((sport) => {
    return <option key={sport}>{sport}</option>
  })}
</select>
```

But when I attempt to combine both, it fails to render any options, excluding the "Select a Sport":

```html
<select className="selectpicker">
  <option>Select a Sport</option>
  {Object.keys(this.props.sports).map((sport) => {
    return <option key={sport}>{sport}</option>
  })}
</select>
```

The `this.props.sports` is a `prop` that is getting pulled from a remote source, so the data may take a few seconds to return, which I think is causing the issue. I have the following in `componentWillMount`, which returns `this.props.sports` (from redux).

```js
componentWillMount(){
  this.props.fetchSports();
}
```

I believe this is the case because when I define an object, `returnedSports`, for what will be returned in `this.props.sports`, and use that to loop through, the select options render.

```html
<select className="selectpicker">
  <option>Select a Sport</option>
  {Object.keys(returnedSports).map((sport) => {
    return <option key={sport}>{sport}</option>
  })}
</select>
```

What do I need to modify in my render to be able to use both bootstrap-select and ReactJS?

Comment: It's better to use `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount`, but I'm not sure that it's the reason

Comment: @lunochkin there is no such thing as "better", depends on the use case ;)

Comment: there is lack of context as for use case itself

Comment: did you find a way as I am also facing the same issue?